# LDPC: Hard_decision decoding algorithm

Tags: vector, decode

I am working with Bit-flipping decoding [Hard_decision] for one bit flip.

I have followed for below `H_matrix` :"For the bit-flipping algorithm the messages passed along the Tanner graph edges are also binary:  a bit node sends a message declaring if it is a one or a zero, and each check node sends a message to each connected bit node, declaring what value the bit is based on the information available to the check node.

The check node determines that its parity-check equation is satisfied if the modulo-2 sum of the incoming bit values is zero. If the majority of the messages received by a bit node are different from its received value the bit node changes (flips) its current value. This process is repeated until all of the parity-check equations are satisfied.

Correct `codeword = [10010101]`

`H matrix[4][8] = {{0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1},   {1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0}}`;

`ReceivedCodeWord[8]={1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1};` //Error codeword

I need to get `[10010101]` but instead i am getting `[10010001]` for `ReceivedCodeWord[8] = {1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1}`.

But for other possible ReceivedCodeWord i am getting correct.

e.g. ReceivedCodeWord `[00010101]` i am getting correct codeword `[10010101]`
ReceivedCodeWord `[11010101]` i am getting correct codeword [10010101].

Doubt: why for `ReceivedCodeWord {1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1}` i am getting `[10010001]`, its totally wrong. Please explain me.

Here's [a link](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/ldpc-bit-flipping-decoding-hard-decision.151500/#post-1301248)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the liner block code you used. Firstly, this code isn't a LDPC code, since the `H` martix doesn't satisfy the row-column constraint (e.g., the 3-th colmun and the 6-th column have 1s in two same poistions).

**(1)** When `{1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1}` is received , the check sums are `{0,1,1,0}`. If you use multiple bit flipping decoding algorithm, which means more than one bit can be flipped during one iteration, the 3-th variable node and 6-th variable node will be flipped together since both of them connect two unsatisfied check nodes, then the result will be `{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1}` after first iteration. During the second iteration, the check sums are still `{0,1,1,0}`, so the 3-th variable node and 6-th variable node will be flipped again, this process will be recurrent in later iterations.

**(2)** The minimum Hamming distance of this code is 2, so this code can dectect 1 erros and correct 0.5 errors. Even you use single bit flipping decoding algorithm, it will has 50% probability to decode the received codeword `{1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1}` as another vaild codeword `{1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1}`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for late response ;)